# Holomorphic primitive of $1/z$ on an arbitrary domain

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be an arbitrary domain not containing $0$. Assume that the function $\frac{1}{z}$ has a holomorphic primitive $F$ on $D$. Show that for some constant $c \in \mathbb C$:$$F(z)+c \in \operatorname{Ln}(z)\ \   \forall z \in D.$$
To my knowledge the function $1/z$ has a holomorphic primitive $\ln|z|+i\operatorname{arg}(z)$ on $\mathbb C\setminus{\mathbb R_+} $. But how can I construct something similar for a unknown domain? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{F(z)}}z$. Then$$f'(z)=\frac{z\frac1ze^{F(z)}-e^{F(z)}}{z^2}=0.$$Therefore, $f$ is constant. Besides, $f\not\equiv0$. Therefore, $\frac{e^{F(z)}}z=e^c$, for some $c\in\mathbb C$, which means that $e^{F(z)}=ze^{c}$. So, $F(z)$ is a $c$ plus a logarithm of $z$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $z\mapsto{1\over z}$ has no primitive in $\dot{\mathbb C}$, but it has a primitive, e.g., in $\Omega:={\mathbb C}\setminus{\mathbb R}_{\leq0}$, called the *principal value of the logarithm*:
$${\rm Log}(z)=\log|z|+i{\rm Arg}(z)\ ,$$
whereby $${\rm Arg}(z):={\rm the}\bigl({\rm arg}(z)\,\cap\>]-\pi,\pi[\>\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$ 
Here ${\rm arg}(z)$ is an infinite set of values differing by multiples of $2\pi$, and ${\rm Arg}(z)$ extracts the unique value in the interval $\>]-\pi,\pi[\>$ out of this set.

Now in your case you have a domain $D$ which need not be part of $\Omega$. Nevertheless $z\mapsto{1\over z}$ may have a global holomorphic primitive $F$ in $D$: Imagine $D$ to be a 2D sausage that winds without selfintersections a few times around $0$, but does not contain a loop around $0$. The statement you are told to prove is the following: Each point $z_0\in D$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that for a suitable constant $c$ one has
$$F(z)+c \ \in \  \log|z|+i{\rm arg}(z)\qquad(z\in U)\tag{2}$$
(note the "$\in$" instead of a "$=$" !).

For the *proof* extract from the set ${\rm arg}(z)$ a continuous representant valid in $U$ (similarly to $(1)$), and obtain in this way a holomorphic function $z\mapsto \ell(z)$ representing the idea of $\log$ in $U$. Then $$\ell'(z)={1\over z}=F'(z)\qquad(z\in U)\ ,$$
from which we can infer $\ell(z)-F(z)={\rm const.}$ in $U$, hence $(2)$.